# how to calculate the multivariable limit?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

I need to show that the function $f(x,y)=\frac{x^5+y^6}{|x|^3+|y|^3}$ is continuous at (0,0), so I want to show that 
$ \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^5+y^6}{|x|^3+|y|^3} =0$

I tried switching to polar coordinates but did not see how that helps. what would be a good way to calculate the limit?

Comment: I suppose that you have $f(0,0)=0$. As $(x,y)\to (0,0)$, you may suppose that $x^2+y^2\leq 1$,  then  you have $|x^5|=|x|^3.|x|^2\leq |x|^3(x^2+y^2)$, and  $|y|^6=|y|^3.|y|^3\leq |y|^3.|y^2|\leq |y|^3(x^2+y^2)$.

Comment: Strictly speaking you **can't** prove this function is continuous at (0, 0) because it is **not** continuous there!  It is not even defined at (0, 0).  I presume you have the additional condition that f(0)= 0 but neglected to write that.

Comment: yes, f(0)=0, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's enough to show $\;\dfrac{\lvert x^5+y^6\rvert}{\lvert x\rvert^3+\lvert y\rvert^3}$ tend to $0$. Now, setting $x=r\cos\theta$, $y=r\sin\theta$, we have
$$\dfrac{\lvert x^5+y^6\rvert}{\lvert x\rvert^3+\lvert y\rvert^3}\le\dfrac{\lvert x\rvert^5+\lvert y^6\rvert}{\lvert x\rvert^3+\lvert y\rvert^3}=\frac{r^5\bigl(\lvert\cos\theta\rvert^5+r\lvert\sin\theta\rvert^6\bigr)}{r^3\bigl(\lvert\cos\theta \rvert^3+\lvert\sin\theta \rvert^3}\le\frac{r^2(1+r)}{\lvert\cos\theta \rvert^3+\lvert\sin\theta \rvert^3}.$$
There remains to show $\lvert\cos\theta \rvert^3+\lvert\sin\theta \rvert^3$ has a positive lower bound. For this, we may suppose $0\le \theta\le \pi/2$, so that
\begin{align}
\lvert\cos\theta \rvert^3+\lvert\sin\theta \rvert^3&=\cos\theta^3+\sin^3\theta=(\sin\theta+\cos\theta)(1+\sin\theta\cos\theta)\\&\ge\sin\theta+\cos\theta=\sqrt2\sin\Bigl(\theta+\frac\pi4\Bigr)\ge1\qquad\text{if }\;0\le \theta\le \frac\pi2.
\end{align}
Thus $\;\dfrac{\lvert x^5+y^6\rvert}{\lvert x\rvert^3+\lvert y\rvert^3}\le r^2(1+r)$, which tends to $0$ when $r$ tends to $0$.

Comment: could you explain why it's necessary that the lower bound is positive?

Comment: If it's  $0$,  you can't get an upper bound for the fraction.